# List initialization for array<array<int, M>, N>

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, stl, list-initialization

When initializing a 2D array we can do

```
int data[2][2] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}; // OK
```

we can also use

```
int data[2][2] = {1, 2, 3, 4}; // OK
```

which makes sense since a 2D array still is a continues chunk of memory.

When using the array class instead of the base type, this works

```
array<array<int, 2>, 2> data = {1, 2, 3, 4}; // OK
```

Which again makes sense, since array class doesn't have any extra data and ends up as a continues chunk of memory as well.

But the 2D list does not work:

```
array<array<int, 2>, 2> data = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}; // Error
```

I can also initialize this

```
vector<array<int, 2>> data = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}; // OK
```

But couldn't find anyway to initialize:

```
array<vector<int>, 2> = ????
```

My question is:

Is there a fundamental design reason for this (My guess is something related to stuff happening at compile-time vs run-time)? Or is this just an implementation decision for the compiler I am using (GCC)?

Comment: `std::array<std::array<int, 2>, 2> a = {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}};` You need to use double brace initialization.

Comment: **EDIT:** Example with 2 and 3 dimensions: https://ideone.com/ugs1E6 The double brace initialization is needed for > 1 dimension. This is prior to `CWG 1270 revision` which I read from the example given here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array Apparently it used to be required for 1 dimension.

Comment: `vector` has an explicit constructor, so if you have an array of vectors, you have to write out `vector{1, 2}` etc. for each sub element

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::array` doesn't have any user-defined constructor (like `std::vector`), it just contains a underlying array, when performing aggregate initialization you need one more braces for it.

```
array<array<int, 2>, 2> data = {{{{1, 2}}, {{3, 4}}}};
//                             ^                    ^  <- for array<array<int, 2>, 2>
//                              ^                  ^   <- for the underlying array
//                               ^      ^              <- for the 1st array<int, 2>
//                                ^    ^               <- for its underlying array
//                                         ^      ^    <- for the 2nd array<int, 2>
//                                          ^    ^     <- for its underlying array
```

We can omit braces as

```
array<int, 2> data = {1, 2};
array<array<int, 2>, 2> data = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

because of [brace elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization):

> The braces around the nested initializer lists may be elided (omitted), in which case as many initializer clauses as necessary are used to initialize every member or element of the corresponding subaggregate, and the subsequent initializer clauses are used to initialize the following members of the object.

That means the above code code be written as

```
array<array<int, 2>, 2> data = {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}};
```

And `array<array<int, 2>, 2> data = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};` fails because it's interpreted as:

```
array<array<int, 2>, 2> data = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
//                             ^              ^  <- for array<array<int, 2>, 2>
//                              ^    ^           <- for the underlying array
//                                      ^    ^   <- excess elements; std::array has only one underlying array
```